# How to properly use new version of a Package in Python (patsy)? Have already Installed, but it continues to use the old version

Tags: python, installation, version, uninstallation, patsy

1. On my Python 3.7.2, I need the package patsy 0.5.1

   2. -pip install patsy (led to 0.5.1) being installed
   3. The following code still shows patsy 0.5.0
      `import patsy`
      `patsy.__version__`
   4. pip uninstall patsy AND pip uninstall patsy==0.5.0 lead to only 0.5.1 being uninstalled

Is this a problem specific to this package? Or is there a generally accepted safe way to do this? Are cleanups like this usually necessary?

Is manually deleting any patsy 0.5.0 folders not advised?

Comment: Show us the output of `pip --version` and `python --version`.

Comment: @JohnGordon the versions are
pip --version: pythonpip 19.2.3
python -- version: Python 3.7.2

Comment: @JohnGordon hmm, patsy version 0.5.1 seems to be working now.  I had tried closing and opening my workbook in Jupyter Notebook.  It seems I had to restart the whole session.  (It's the only thing I did different today)